# libgdx get triangles from mesh

Tags: mesh, libgdx

I'm using libgdx for a school project and I need some help.

I am working on a 3d game that uses Bullet physics engine that (ndk).

I have managed to connect it and everything works, now I need to pass the physics engine all the triangles from the mesh object (that is loaded from a OBJ).

I have tried using mesh->getIndices() but it returns 0 (is it possible i have additional values that mess up the obj loader?) and vertices (the first three decimals returned from Mesh->getVertices(vertices) - this is probably wrong since the vertices arent sorted?) but collisions act strange.

Does any one know how to get all triangles from a mesh in libgdx?